# how to compare integer value and values we are getting from params after form submission in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to compare two values one is integer with the params value which I got from from submission.

```
if params[:activity_log][:user_id]==3 
  @points=@points+50
else
  puts "Condition failed"
end
```

But even if condition is true it is going to else part.

Comment: could you output your params so we could see how they are nested

Comment: Paste your params in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should convert params[:activity_log][:user_id] into integer and then compare.

```
if params[:activity_log][:user_id].to_i==3 
    @points=@points+50
else
    puts "Condition failed"
end
```